# Centos Crashed After Removing Some Packages

Tags: boot, centos

I was cleaning up packages I don't use, and I found that I have the emacs package installed but I don't use emacs. So I ran this command to make sure I don't have any emacs:

```
sudo yum remove *emacs*
```

It ran for a while, but then right after it finished my computer crashed and it showed this screen with a bunch of log output. I restarted my computer, and when centos booted up, it just took me to a shell screen. I tried reinstalling the packages with

```
sudo yum install *emacs*
```

but after I restart my computer it shows the same screen again. How do I get centos back to normal? I was using the GNOME desktop environment.

Comment: I have no idea why someone spinelessly took a point from you without telling you what you did wrong.  Here.. I will give it back.  ;^)  It doesn't help solve your problem but I only use CENTOS when doing commercial development for RedHat.  I have had too many darned problems with those distros.

Answer (score 0):

Running `yum remove *emacs*` will indeed delete a lot, as it will remove `emacs-filesystem` which some packages are dependent upon.

If you have not run another `yum` command successfully, you can restore how things were by simply:

```
yum history undo last
```

If you have, then you can unwind the last operations by examining what they were with `yum history` and then `yum history undo <transaction ID>`.